# Wrong border position on tabular when using lstlisting

Tags: tables, listings

I have encountered a problem while using `tabular` environment. The following code

```
\documentclass [12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage {listings}
\usepackage {fontspec}
\usepackage {enumitem} 
\usepackage {parskip}
\usepackage {setspace} 

\lstnewenvironment{sqlcode}[2][]%
{%
  %\minipage{\textwidth} 
  \lstset{
    basicstyle={\footnotesize\ttfamily\singlespacing},
    language=SQL,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true, 
    captionpos=none,
    numbers=none,
    frame=none,
    tabsize=2,
    extendedchars=true,
    caption=#1,
    label=#2
  }
}
{  
  %\endminipage
}


\begin {document}

\begin {center}
  \begin {table}
    \begin {tabular}{| l | l | l | p{5cm} |}
    \hline
    \textbf {Table Name} & \multicolumn {3}{c |}{  } \\ \hline
    Attribute & Description & Type & Example \\ \hline
    SQL Code & \multicolumn {3}{ l |}{ }
    {
      \begin{sqlcode}[SQL Code for Project table]{sqlproject}
      CREATE TABLE project
      (
        projectid bigint NOT NULL,
        name character varying(255),
        description character varying(255),
        address character varying(255),
        projectpriority character varying(255),
        CONSTRAINT project_pkey PRIMARY KEY (projectid)
      )
      WITH (
        OIDS=FALSE
      );
      \end{sqlcode} 
    } \tabularnewline \hline
  \end {tabular} 
  \caption {Table Properties}
  \end {table}

\end {center}

\end {document}
```

generates the following output:

[image: Wrong Table Border]

The problem is that the table border is not displayed correctly in third row. Am I missing something?

Comment: It seems to me that your mistake is that extra brackets  appear on `\multicolumn {3}{ l |}{ }{text}`. Should be `\multicolumn {3}{ l |}{text}`.

Comment: @Dox I tried removing those brackets but the problem persists.

Comment: I took your code and try to compile... but no luck! How are you compiling?

Comment: Even removing the whole `sqlcode` environment the problem remains. So the problem is not related with it.

Comment: @Dox I use latexmk (xelatex for typesetting) for compiling to pdf. I am using Debian Jessie.

Comment: @Dox, since the package `fontspec` was loaded you have to run `lualatex` for example instead of `pdflatex`, or comment the package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is related to your use of `\multicolumn`, which takes three arguments. The first gives the span of the columns, the second provides an updated column specification for the merged column, and the final one the content. You've provided "four". Even if you were to use `\multicolumn{3}{l|}{<sqlcode>}` you would still have a problem since you're passing *verbatim*-like content to a macro... something that is not easily done in LaTeX. You can circumvent this by boxing the content before passing it to `\multicolumn`:

[image]

```
\documentclass [12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings

\lstnewenvironment{sqlcode}[2][]%
{%
  %\minipage{\textwidth} 
  \lstset{
    basicstyle={\footnotesize\ttfamily\singlespacing},
    language=SQL,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true, 
    captionpos=none,
    numbers=none,
    frame=none,
    tabsize=2,
    extendedchars=true,
    caption=#1,
    label=#2
  }%
}
{%
  %\endminipage
}
\newsavebox{\sqlbox}

\begin {document}

\begin{lrbox}{\sqlbox}
\begin{sqlcode}[SQL Code for Project table]{sqlproject}
CREATE TABLE project
(
  projectid bigint NOT NULL,
  name character varying(255),
  description character varying(255),
  address character varying(255),
  projectpriority character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT project_pkey PRIMARY KEY (projectid)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
\end{sqlcode} 
\end{lrbox}

\begin {table}
  \begin {tabular}{| l | l | l | p{5cm} |}
    \hline
    \textbf {Table Name} & \multicolumn {3}{c |}{  } \\ \hline
    Attribute & Description & Type & Example \\ \hline
    SQL Code & \multicolumn {3}{ l |}{\raisebox{0pt}[\dimexpr\height-\normalbaselineskip]{\usebox{\sqlbox}}} \\ \hline
  \end {tabular} 
  \caption {Table Properties}
\end {table}

\end {document}
```

Some other changes have also been made to the code.

Comment: Great use of `\savebox` and `\usebox`. Thank you for such a wonderful solution.